# IntelliJ, PhpStorm: Debugging with xdebug ignores XDEBUG_SESSION cookie

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, xdebug

I am trying to debug a Drupal website with the PHP plugin in Intellij (would be the same in PhpStorm).

I have the following setup:

Chrome Browser pointing to a localhost alias `mydomain.local` and the XDebug Helper extension is installed and set to Debug. In the *Developer Tools* under Cookies I can see that the `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie is set to PHPSTORM.

I have configured php with the xdebug plugin using the following settings:

```
xdebug.extended_info = 1
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

In IntelliJ I have setup a Server pointing to `mydomain.local` and in the run configuration I am using that server and have set the Ide Key to `PHPSTORM`.

Now the issue is this:

If I enable **Break at first line in PHP scripts**, then the debugger immediately breaks at the first breakable location inside the `index.php`. If I disable that option, I get a warning that no breakpoint was hit, even though I have a break point set and I am certain that the code is being executed. The warning that I see looks like this:

```
Debug session was finished without being paused
It may be caused by path mappings misconfiguration or not synchronized
local and remote projects.
To figure out the problem check path mappings configuration for 
'mydomain.local' server at PHP|Servers or enable Break at first line in
PHP scripts option (from Run menu).
```

Now if I explicitly use a URL with the following query parameter appended: `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` then all my breakpoints are properly being breaked in IntelliJ.

**Question:** Why is the `XDEBUG_SESSION` cookie being ignored?

**Update:** Added my PHP and XDebug version output from `php -v`:

```
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016,
    by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

and my Apache virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain
    ServerName mydomain.local
    <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mydomain.log
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update 2:**
I have a php extension installed that is called `fpm`. I am not quite sure why its installed or if I need it. I think it was automatically installed with php. Could this be interfering?

Comment: Have you tried setting `remote_autostart` to 0? It seems unnecessary to set this option to 1 if you want to enable debugging by setting the cookie.

Comment: Also, what's your xdebug version?

Comment: Check if your website does some redirect, which might be the cause for it not breaking where you expect. Although it sounds as if that isn't the case since it works when you add the GET parameter.

Comment: Setting `remote_autostart` to 0 did not help. I have updated my question to include the php and xdebug version and also the apache configuration. There is no redirect happening that I am aware of. One more thing that I just noticed is that the message *Debug session was finished without being paused* appears three times when I refresh the page in the browser a single time.

Comment: **1)** Instead of debugging real Drupal code -- can you create a simple .php file with few one-liner instructions and try to debug that one instead -- will it work? For example (just make then one per line): `<?php $a = 1; $b = 2; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;` **2)** As I understand the debug actually works .. but it either needs GET parameter or auto-debug .. because COOKIE alone does not do the job -- right? If so -- it must be either xdebug issue (as it's xdebug who initiates debug connection) or browser/web server config issue (e.g. cookie gets stripped/altered) -- can you see it in `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: **3)** What xdebug log has to say about such unsuccessful sessions?

Comment: *"... appears three times when I refresh the page in the browser a single time"* This could mean that you have some scripts that run 3 times (e.g. your 404 script gets triggered when you do not have `favicon.ico` or alike)

Comment: Yes, seems there is some Javascript that is doing additional requests. So thats probably not the issue.

Comment: Here is the xdebug.log output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23415690/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127174/discussion-between-lanoxx-and-lazyone).

Comment: @lanoxx Please share your solution as an answer -- it will be useful for other people in the same circumstances (questions with accepted answers are easier to find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out the problem was not in IntelliJ or PhpStorm, but rather Drupal specific. In particular I needed to disable all caching.

The article [Disable Drupal 8 caching during development](https://www.drupal.org/node/2598914) explains in detail the steps to do that.

After I had disabled the caching Drupal everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

I used to have this issue when I've "*overconfigured*" my setup.

1. You might want to try adding the [XDebug helper extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc) to chrome
2. After adding that go to the plugin's settings and select PhpStorm:

[image: XDebug Helper Settings]

3. Try striping down your xdebug config to these values only:

*(works on my box)*

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

4. The PhpStorm config should contain debug port 9000 and [X] Can accept external connections:

[image: PhpStorm Xdebug Settings]

5. Then you should have listening to debug connections in PhpStorm on:

[image: PhpStorm Debug Listening]

6. Also enable debugging in your browser (via the xdebug helper):

[image: Xdebug helper Debug]

7. If the bug icon is green [image: xdebug helper debugging on], then if you refresh the page, you should be good to go, and PhpStorm should stop at the first breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in PHPStorm 9 while debugging code inside a virtual machine. But first you questions:

**Question:** Why is the XDEBUG_SESSION cookie being ignored?

**Answer**: I don't know exactly but I suspect based on that it works when you explicitly specify `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` or "break on first line", it is ignoring the incoming request. It will do it's work but don't stop on break points because it thinks it's not needed for the current request.

**My solution**

What helped me was adding the remote host name/ip to the xdebug, when debugging for browser call. Or `export` those setting when debugging from command line.

for xdebug.ini

```
xdebug.remote_host=mydomain.local;
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
```

for command line usage:

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=mydomain.local; php -dxdebug.remote_autostart=1 -dxdebug.remote_connect_back=1 -dxdebug.remote_host=mydomain.local ./script.php
```

Then setting up `path mapping` . To do this go to `Settings` -> `Languages & Frameworks` -> `PHP` -> `Server`.
In there select the server you set up e.g. `mydomain.local`  if existing and enter `mydomain.local` as host name, with port `80` and `XDEBUG`.
Now check the "Use path mappings" and scroll down to your index.php or some other uniqe entry point you can reach from the browser. 
The next one sounds stupid but worked for me. If your `index.php` is located under `/home/lanoxx/project/index.php` enter the **same** location under "Absolute path on the server". Then set a breakboint in the `index.php` file and load page from browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you use fpm and nginx, maybe you specified for `fastcgi_pass` FastCGI-server which works on port `9000` by default. If it so, set another free port for Xdebug, for example `9009`

Answer (score 0):

Try these configuration and see if it helps

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1 <-------- THIS
xdebug.remote_enable = 1 <----------- AND THIS
```